# Access CoreData from multiple applications

Tags: macos, core-data

I'm wondering how I could access one CoreData storage from multiple applications developed separatedly on macOS. I'd like to share some master data among them.

Comment: This question feels a little vague, what is it more precisely you're asking about?

Comment: Well, I'd like to have one CoreData model/storage and more apps using the same model and sharing data.